# Send file from electron to server connected in LAN

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, client-server, desktop-application

I am building a client desktop application that uploads a file and sends it to store on the server.

Conditions:

- Client-server connected in LAN
- Send file without using internet
- File system for storage on server (no database)

**Electron.js** is used for building the desktop application. What should run on the server-side to receive and store files? Is there a library in electron to send files over a LAN?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a server running on local network, it should work just any data transfer. You can have a node server handling requests and you access it via local ip address.